# Sending image over TCP/IP

Tags: c#, tcp, remote-desktop

I am working on a personal projet, as first task I need the TCP server to send a specific number of screenshots to the client while the client is asking to it. In this exemple The client can only receive two images over ten, I don't now why it stops after that. I suspect that it's related to receiving buffer of the client. 
Client.cs :

```
string serverName = "localhost";
int serverPort = 7;

TcpClient client;
NetworkStream netStream;
int readBytes = 0;

try
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        client = new TcpClient(serverName, serverPort);
        netStream = client.GetStream();
        Console.WriteLine("Receiving ....");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[500000];
        while ((readBytes = netStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {}
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer);
        Image receivedImg = Image.FromStream(ms);
        receivedImg.Save(@"C:\Users\fm_pc\Desktop\screen\test");
        buffer.Initialize();
        netStream.Close();
        client.Close();
    }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error in Sender : {0}", ex.Message);
}
```

Server.cs :

```
int port = 7;
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
listener.Start();

//Send screenshots to connected client:

try
{
    SceenShoter sceenShote = new SceenShoter();
    Image imgToSend;
    TcpClient client;
    NetworkStream netStream;
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
    netStream = client.GetStream();

    imgToSend = sceenShote.GetScreenShot();
    imgToSend.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    byte[] buffer = ms.ToArray();

    netStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);                   

    client.Close();
    netStream.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error in the receiver : {0}", ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Of course, this while loop is a waiting loop, the client waits there till it received whole data sent by the server.

Comment: It looks to me like it keeps writing to the same buffer. So if the while loop executes twice, for example, the results from the first iteration will be lost.

Comment: You have to send a byte count at the beginning of the image, then at receive end read the byte count and then continue reading until the entire image is read.

Comment: Hint: `netStream.CopyTo(ms)` would be your friend...